# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT returning different results

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Following MySQL Query return me 49 rows but "Total" in each rows is displayed as 48.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.CIN, t1.Name, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CIN) FROM `cSignatoryAssociations` WHERE DIN ='00016902') As Total
FROM `cSignatoryAssociations` t2
LEFT JOIN `cRoC` t1 ON t1.CIN = t2.CIN
WHERE t2.DIN='00016902'  
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(t1.CIN,9,4) DESC;
```

When following code is run separately i get expected results i.e 49.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CIN) FROM `cSignatoryAssociations` WHERE DIN ='00016902'
```

Please help me figure out what is wrong.

Comment: `DISTINCT t2.CIN, t1.Name` is something different than `DISTINCT t2.CIN`

Comment: yes it will since for each row you are counting the same thing again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CIN) FROM `cSignatoryAssociations` WHERE DIN ='00016902'
```

returns 49 rows. But this is a sub Select and the main Select have also a Distinct.

The Main Select with the Distinct will remove lines that are the sames and this will be the case.

The Whole Select will return 49 Rows, but there are 2 same tuple and Distinct will remove one. So the result will be 48 Rows.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. Can you also suggest some solution for it?

Comment: like someone already said, the sub select will always return the same value. So it means in the main select are 2 tuple that are equal. You could not use distinct but this wouldn't solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
SELECT t2.CIN, t1.Name, COUNT(t2.CIN)
FROM `cSignatoryAssociations` t2
LEFT JOIN `cRoC` t1 ON t1.CIN = t2.CIN
WHERE t2.DIN='00016902'  
GROUP BY t1.Name
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(t1.CIN,9,4) DESC;
```

One thing i dont know what you want do but just make sure you want `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`. because they dont give same result.

Comment: This didn't worked. COUNT(t2.CIN) will always be 1 coz all 49 records are unique by CIN.

Comment: then change the group by to `GROUP BY t1.Name` OR some column else which you want to be distinged.